# CDI2.0 Why can't the BeanManager fire Async Events?

Tags: events, jakarta-ee, asynchronous, cdi

I am testing the new CDI2.0 pre-release and I was expecting the BeanManager to be able to fire events asynchronously.

In **CDI 1.2** I was doing this:

```
@Inject
BeanManager beanManager;

public void fireEvents() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            beanManager.fireEvent(new LightEvent("Light Event " + i));
            beanManager.fireEvent(new HeavyEvent("Heavy Event " + i));
        }
    }
```

As I wanted to test **async events**, I saw that the BeanManager  does not have a fireAsync() method. Instead, I have to fire the events the other way:

```
@Inject
private Event<LightEvent> lightEvent;

@Inject
private Event<HeavyEvent> heavyEvent;

public void fireAsyncEvents() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        lightEvent.fireAsync(new LightEvent("light " + i));
        heavyEvent.fireAsync(new HeavyEvent("heavy " + i));
    }
}
```

Now this works fine, but I have to define the events first.
**Are there any plans to add a fireAsync() method to the Beanmanager ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because a decision was taken not to bloat `BeanManager` (BM) that much. To elaborate further, there were people asking for `fireAsync` as well as people asking for option to fire event directly from BM with selected qualifiers or type, or type and qualifiers. All of those are *valid requirements* but adding all this onto BM would bloat this "uber" entry point even more.

Therefore, a decision was made to instead create `BeanManager#getEvent()` from which you get into an `Event` interface directly. From there you can do `select(..)` based on desired qualifiers/types (or leave it default) and you then `fire` (for sync events) or `fireAsync` (for async).

To support my statements above, you can read more in related [CDI issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/CDI-633) or check [the pull request](https://github.com/cdi-spec/cdi/pull/334) directly.

**So what you are after is already there and probably looks like this**:

```
@Inject
BeanManager bm;

public void myMethod() {
  // default one
  bm.getEvent().fireAsync(new MyPayload());
  // with selections of subtype and qualifiers
  bm.getEvent().select(MyType.class, MyQualifier.class).fireAsync(new MyPayload());
}
```